# Weakened conditions on the smoothness of the domain in the regularity and a priori estimate of Agmon, Douglis, and Nirenberg for elliptic systems

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, reference-request, elliptic-pde

I have read in a couple of places (e.g. *An Introduction to PDEs* by Renardy and Rogers, p.309) that the smoothness hypotheses on the domain in the a priori estimate of Agmon, Douglis, and Nirenberg for elliptic systems can be weakened, but I haven't found a resource that goes into any detail yet. Can anybody point me towards a reference?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hi.

I don't clearly know the detail in the book by Renardy and Rogers. But one good book to look at for regularity/ a priori estimates for elliptic systems and calculus of variations for vector-valued functions is:

M. GIAQUINTA, Multiple Integrals in the Calculus of Variations and Nonlinear Elliptic Systems, Princeton U. Press, Princeton, 1983.